# how to make a zoom tools to zoom image like Google Maps?

Tags: php, html, css, image

I want to ask about my project. So, I have a webpage that show the image. But I want people can zoom the image when they want to see more details about the image like the Zoom tools in Google Maps by clicking the image. Can somebody tell me the way it could be done? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You need very different solutions if you have very big images or small ones :

- for small images (a few Mo), you may send the image to the browser and have a small script handling the mouse and wheel and drawing on a canvas the visible portion of the image.
- If you have very big images, you need a solution similar to the Google Maps one. The interesting point about Google Maps zoom is that your browser never gets the whole high definition map but only "tiles", that is small part at the screen resolution. You need a server side library to cut the big images and build the tiles. Many are available (I made one in Java), it depends on your server side language of choice (google "tiling zoom library your_language" for example). And you need a (somewhat complex) script browser side to fetch, manage and display the tiles.

Comment: so I have big images and i use it for php. So what do you think?

Comment: What size are your images ? More than 1 Mo ?

Comment: I never did this in PHP but it seems there exists a few libraries. For example http://www.sharewareconnection.com/ajax-zoom-image-zoom-pan-gallery.htm

Comment: there are no size more than 1 Mo. but almost 1 Mo.

Comment: In this case, if your users can wait for the download of a 1 Mo file, I strongly advise you not to use a tiling library as that's a lot of work to use, but simply a zooming script based on mousewheel and a canvas.

Comment: okay I'll try first of what you've advised to me and I will see the result. Thank You.